# How to build Xabber from bash?

Tags: android, linux, bash, build

I have a specific open-source Android project I want to build. It's Xabber, Android Jabber application.

https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android

I have Debian Linux and bash. How to build this thing, preferably only using programs in debian repositories?

Also, in order to be less specific and more general: How to tell, from a project like this, what building system was used, what is the structure, how to build it, what to do exactly, where to begin.

(I have zero knowledge of Android development, so I am sorry if the question is too trivial or too specific.)

note: I want to build this application so I can run it on my Android phone. I don't want to publish it further.

Comment: I voted for my own question to be closed as too broad. It's from 2013, so I did not know better back then; plus in 2019, the code has actual instructions for build. I don't want to delete it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2019, there is a very clear way how to build Xabber, on the github page.

This question in general is too broad to be answered correctly.